# orientation incorrectly reported in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have an app that needs to load a different image as the background image depending on the orientation of the device. I have the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
BOOL isLandScape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation);

if (isLandScape)
{
    self.bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"login_bg748.png"];        
}
```

For some reason even if the simulator starts in landscape this bool is still false. I checked and it always reports being in portrait mode regardless of the actual simulator orientation. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is not working?

In shouldAutoRotateForInterfaceOrientation I have the following:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"login_bg748.png"];
    } else
    {
        self.bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"login_bg1004.png"];        
    }

    return YES;
```

And this code does work, its just the startup that is messed up. After I perform one rotation it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that `viewDidLoad` is too early. Every app launches in portrait and later rotates to landscape. When `viewDidLoad` is called, the rotation has not happened yet. You want to use delayed performance, or put your tests in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` or similar. See the explanation in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_rotation

Comment: I used didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation and it worked. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

First in the function`shouldAutoRotateForInterfaceOrientation` you just have to `return YES`

now use this function

```
        -(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
     {

             if  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
                {
                         //landscape view login
                 }
             else 
                {
                        //portrait View logic
                 }
     }
```

And if you are already in landscape view or portrait view then in your `viewDidLoad` function

```
        -(void)viewDidLoad
        {
           if  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
         {
                 //landscape view code
            } 

         else
         {
              //portrait view code
         }

       }
```

hope this will help

Comment: If every app launches in portrait mode then why check it in viewDidLoad like that?

Comment: I doubt that every single app launches in portrait mode. It depends on the requirement. for example on iphone6+, iPhone 7+ you can use the phone in landscape mode, so if user launches your app in landscape mode then the code in `viewdidload` will take care of the appropriate view to be shown to the user and if he changes to portrait mode while using the app, we have our `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation ` to take care for it